# Resizing a SurfaceView such that a grid of squares can perfectly fit inside it

Tags: android, android-canvas, surfaceview

I'm working on an android game almost exactly the same as [flood-it](http://unixpapa.com/floodit/?sz=10&nc=6). I'm drawing a grid of coloured squares in a surface view via calls to Canvas.drawRect. The problem I encounter is when the size of the grid of squares (eg. 14 squares x 14 squares) is not evenly divisible into the dimensions of the surface view in pixels, I end up with a small empty border around the surface view.

For instance, (Looking at things on a very small scale for demonstration purposes) if I needed to draw a grid of 2 squares x 2 squares on a surface view that was 15 pixels x 15 pixels, I could draw the squares as 7 pixels x 7 pixels each, but that would make all 4 squares cover an area of 14 pixels squared, leaving me with a small 1 pixel border around the right and bottom of the surface view that looks bad.

My question is how I go about solving this. I have the surface view defined in my layout file as 350dp x 350dp.